# Python - numpy mgrid and reshape

Tags: numpy

Can someone explain to me what the second line of this code does?

```
objp = np.zeros((48,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:8,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
```

Can someone explain to me what exactly the np.mgrid[0:8,0:6] part of the code is doing and what exactly the T.reshape(-1,2) part of the code is doing?

Thanks and good job!

Comment: It creates a (2,8,6) array, transposes it to (6,8,2), and reshapes to (48,2)

Comment: Thanks @Bo Peng, I had the same doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line creates a [multi-dimensional mesh grid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html), [transposes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) it, [reshapes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) it so that it represents two columns and inserts it into the first two columns of the objp array.

**Breakdown:**

np.mgrid[0:8,0:6] creates the following mgrid:

```
>> np.mgrid[0:8,0:6] 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
```

The .T transposes the matrix, and the .reshape(-1,2) then reshapes it into two a two-column array shape. These two columns are then the correct shape to replace two columns in the original array.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to see these is to use smaller values for [`mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
In [11]: np.mgrid[0:2,0:3]
Out[11]:
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])

In [12]: np.mgrid[0:2,0:3].T  # (matrix) transpose
Out[12]:
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 2],
        [1, 2]]])

In [13]: np.mgrid[0:2,0:3].T.reshape(-1, 2)  # reshape to an Nx2 matrix
Out[13]:
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Then `objp[:,:2] =` sets the 0th and 1th columns of `objp` to this result.